# Prevent direct access to PHP form handler

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a number of forms in use on my site (Wordpress) that use a PHP file as the 'action' on a form using method="post". All works great, however I am receiving a high number of form submissions that are blank, which occurs when the PHP handler is accessed directly (because my front-end form validation is bypassed by directly accessing the handler file, and the handler include the wp_mail function to send the email).

I am trying to work out how to prevent direct access to the handler file, without breaking the form by preventing access to the handler. If that makes sense?

**Form**

```
<form class="contact-form" action="<?=get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/path/to/my/handler-file.php' ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First name">
    <label for="first_name">First name</label>

    <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last name">
    <label for="last_name">Last name</label>

    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
    <label for="email">Your email</label>

    <button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Handler**

```
// Load WordPress Bootstrap
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );

// To
$to = get_option('admin_email');

// Subject
$subject = 'Contact – ' . $_POST['first_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['last_name']; // Including name ensures new thread in their inbox

// Headers
$headers = array(
    'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['first_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['last_name'] . ' <' . $_POST['email'] . '>'
);

// Data
$message = [];
$message['First name'] = $_POST['first_name'];
$message['Last name'] = $_POST['last_name'];
$message['Email'] = $_POST['email'];

// Blank var to hold data
$message_str = '';

// Push data to $message_str
foreach ($message as $label => $entry) {
    $message_str .= "—\n" . $label . ":\n" . $entry . "\n\n";
}

wp_mail($to, $subject, $message_str, $headers);
```

Comment: You can't really prevent direct access, short of CAPTCHA.  But, checking to ensure there are the expected variables will prevent you from getting blank e-mails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for me, by using the superglobal $_SERVER. From this, I am able to detect the REQUEST_METHOD, which in my case will be POST, as set in my HTML .

```
// Only run if request uses POST method (as set in <form> html)
// This helps to avoid blank submissions, as accessing the file directly will not run
if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ) :

    // My handling code here

// If request does not use POST method, display error
else :
   echo 'Direct access to this file is prohibited.';
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
if(isset($_POST['first-name'], $_POST['last-name'], $_POST['email'])){
   //Do rest of page...
}else{
   //Do nothing or throw error
}
```

To the beginning of your script to check if these have been inputted

Comment: Hi @moshe, could I check the $_SERVER request method instead? i.e if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ) { } else { } endif;